# Java - Find all possible paths based on array key pairs

Tags: java, recursion, regression, dijkstra

I have an array of several key-pairs and i want to find all possible paths from one element and back to it e.g :

```
array { 

a-b
a-c
a-d
b-a
b-c
b-s
d-c
c-a
c-d
c-a
d-a
....

}
```

I'm doing some foreach loops but i'm stuck given the data set . Is there a better way of doing this ?

This is what i did :

1) Separate all keys

```
new array1 = {a,b,c,d,e,f,g......}
```

2) Foreach loops and find its immediate path , e.g :

```
'a' => b , c , d , e ....
'b' => a , c, d, e
```

3) I'm stuck here

a-b , now from b - there are many different paths that it can take and i don;t know how to do nested for each for all the different possible paths .

Any help would be greatly appreciated

What i'm expecting :

```
a-b-a
a-b-c-a
a-b-d-a
a-b-e-a
a-b-c-d-a
a-b-c-e-a
a-c-b-e-a
a-e-c-b-a
.......
```

Comment: Sounds like you've got a problem that falls under the general classification of **graph traversal**.  Nested loops per se can't solve it but there are techniques that can.  Consult a good Data Structures textbook, or just Google "Graph Traversal Java" and start reading...

Comment: @sam.tuver can you please provide the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a loop which continues until all paths start and end with the same node. I.e. you start with a list of a single path containing only the starting node. For each of its neighbors you copy the path, append the neighbor, and add it to the list. Repeat until all paths in the list starts and ends with the same node.

You would also need some check to avoid infinite loops.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to enumerate all possible paths from the given node pairs.
I'm sure I'm forgetting some cases but this should be achievable inside a single loop that traverses the pairs + some cleanup operations:

```
List<Path> paths = new ArrayList<>();
for (Pair p : pairs) {
    // add the path created by this pair
    paths.add(new Path(p));

    // find paths that contain this pair's starting edge and fork them
    List<Path> forkedPaths = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Path path : paths) {
        if (path.contains(p.getStart()) {
          // fork creates a new path: (a-b-c).fork(b-d) = (a-b-d)
          forkedPaths.add(path.fork(p));
        }
    }
    paths.addAll(forkedPaths);
}
removeDuplicates(paths);
```

After this, you should have a list of paths of the sort:

```
a-b-a
c-d
c-d-a
```

Which is easier to check for your intended condition.

This is not computationally optimal but should provide a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look on this class and test it.
It's not the cleanest way to do it, but I guess it's a start.

```
public class TestRecursiveResearch {

    public String[] myList = {"a-b", "a-d", "b-a","b-c","d-c", "c-d"};

    public void search(){
        TreeSet<String> res = new TreeSet<String>();
        for (String pair : myList) {
            String[] splitted = pair.split("-");
            int findedCharFrom = (int)splitted[0].charAt(0);
            int findedCharTo = (int)splitted[1].charAt(0);

            String searchCombination = "";
            if(findedCharFrom < findedCharTo){
                for (int i = findedCharFrom+1 ; i <= findedCharTo; i ++) {
                    searchCombination += "" + (char) i;
                }
            }else{
                for (int i = findedCharFrom-1 ; i >= findedCharTo; i--) {
                    searchCombination += "" + (char) i;
                }
            }

            TreeSet<String> tmpRes = new TreeSet<String>();
            for (String sub : getAllSub(searchCombination)) {
                int n = sub.length();
                tmpRes.addAll(permute(sub, 0, n-1));
            }

            for (String string : tmpRes) {
                res.add((char)findedCharFrom +""+string+""+(char)findedCharFrom);
            }

        }
        for (String string : res) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }

    private TreeSet<String> getAllSub(String str){
        TreeSet<String> allSubs = new TreeSet<String>();
        for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
            allSubs.add(str.substring(i));
            for(int j=i;j<str.length();j++){
                if(j>i){
                    allSubs.add(str.substring(i,j));
                    String res = str.substring(i,j-1) + str.substring(j,str.length());
                    if(!res.equals(""))
                        allSubs.add(res);
                }
            }
        }
        return allSubs;
    }
    private TreeSet<String> permute(String str, int l, int r)
    {
        TreeSet<String> res = new TreeSet<String>();
        if (l == r)
            res.add(str);
        else
        {
            for (int i = l; i <= r; i++)
            {
                str = swap(str,l,i);
                res.addAll(permute(str, l+1, r));
                str = swap(str,l,i);
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    public String swap(String a, int i, int j)
    {
        char temp;
        char[] charArray = a.toCharArray();
        temp = charArray[i] ;
        charArray[i] = charArray[j];
        charArray[j] = temp;
        return String.valueOf(charArray);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TestRecursiveResearch permutation = new TestRecursiveResearch();
        permutation.search();
    }
}
```

And for result :

```
aba
abca
abcda
abda
abdca
aca
acba
acbda
acda
acdba
ada
adba
adbca
adca
adcba
bab
bcb
cdc
dcd
```